# join() merges my current string sandwiched to next iterated string :(?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tuples

```
def interleave(s1,s2):
    zipped_list=list(zip(s1,s2))
    print(zipped_list)
    empty_string=""
    for x in zipped_list:
        empty_string=empty_string.join(x)
        print(empty_string)
print(interleave("hi","bye"))
```

My expectations was the zipped string first part ('h','b') would be joined with the empty string making `empty_string="hb"` and now for next iteration it would become `empty_string="hbiy"` since the next zipped tuple is ('i','y').

But my output was:
`ihby`
Where the first string is sandwiched btwn 2nd string.

Please help me understand this and rectify my wrong implementation. Thanks

Expected Output:
To zip the  two input strings and display as a single string `hbiy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good expect one part where you didn't understand the concept of converting list to string!
Below is the code:

```py
def interleave(s1,s2):
    zipped_list=list(zip(s1,s2))
    print(zipped_list)
    empty_string=""
    for x in zipped_list:
        empty_string+="".join(x)
        print(empty_string)

print (interleave("hi","bye"))
```

This `"".join(x)` convert you tuples to string in the first iteration ('h', 'b') it will output `hb` which is stored in `empty_string` and in the second iteration ('i', 'y') it will output `iy` which will be concatenated to `empty_string`

Comment: Thanks alot :)
One doubt, so join syntax works only with concatenation(+)symbol and then a empty string.join() ?
That's reason mine failed right?
My Understanding was, that ' ' was for a string(which i already have declared, so why use empty quotes, rather pass string name and .join()), but i didnt know about usage of + sign

Comment: @LanAaroon after the first iteration your `empty_string` is no more "" it now "hb"